# "<?xml version="1.0"?>" c# linq or XDocument remove encoding=UTF-8

Tags: c#, xml, linq, encoding, xmltextwriter

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null),
        new XElement(bla));

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"folderpath\index.xml", new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    //writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xdoc.Save(writer);
}
```

I have to generate an XML document which matches exactly my sample. This code however produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

but it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

How can I solve this either with `XMLTextWriter` or linq?

Comment: For `XmlTextWriter`, at least, there's [the `OmitXmlDeclaration` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then manually write the version part of the declaration manually before saving the document. Not sure if there's a nicer solution, this seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `XmlTextWriter` directly. Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) you should be using `XmlWriter.Create` instead.

Answer (score 4):

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5366y21d(v=vs.110).aspx).

> If encoding is null it writes the file out as UTF-8, and omits the encoding attribute from the ProcessingInstruction.

Use:

```
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"folderpath\index.xml", null))
```

Also, see the [source code for `XmlTextWriter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,969).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems to work just fine. And UTF-8 should be the default file encoding anyway, so omitting the encoding shouldn’t cause any problems.